# how to prevent HttpPost that is made from javascript that dosent belong to the project in mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have action method that should be having two features:

1. It cant be accessed from browser URL directly or by get method(Which can be called from external java script files that doesn't belong to project as shown below).

I achieved above feature(Partially) by just adding [HttpPost] attribute to the action method.

Now I cant access directly using URL from browser. Or links click from external sources some thing like a HTML file having this get method call:

```
<a href="http://localhost:52225/Account/Delete/22">Click to play</a>
```

My action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBusinessLayer = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
    employeeBusinessLayer.DeleteEmployee(id);
    return RedirectToAction("ListAllEmployees");
}
```

But I tried to access using java-script post and I was able to access it.

Here is the code. This code is also in an external file and doesn't belong to project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function jsfunction()
        {
            $.post("http://localhost:52225/Account/Delete", {id: 22}, function (data) {
                alert("Please click again");
            });
        };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.button
        {
            font: bold 11px Arial;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            color: #333333;
            padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
            border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-right: 1px solid #333333;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
            border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="jsfunction()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Click to play</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So I feel my problem is not yet solved an hacker can write the above code and will be able to access the HttpPost method.

How to prevent this?

NOTE: I mean I want to give access only to the requests made from button in cshtml view's and also belong to the same project.

Comment: All I know is Session-id is not available for external java-script files where as the MVC view opened in browser will have the Session-id. And I know is in post type call the session-id is compulsory will be transferred to server and get type call doesn't need a session-id. So how come server will give access to post type request that doesn't have session id?.

Comment: A 'Delete' method changes data so it should never have been a GET. Use a form in the view and include the @Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and decorate the method with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. Then check that the current user has the required permission to delete the object.

Comment: Ok I am trying your suggestions. Can any correct me If my comment is wrong regarding get and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MVC Anti Forgery Token to secure it.

In your .cshtml file include `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` 
and then in your Action method check for the Anti Forgery Token:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBusinessLayer = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
    employeeBusinessLayer.DeleteEmployee(id);
    return RedirectToAction("ListAllEmployees");
}
```

Comment: Salt = "MySalt" and MySalt should be removed because Salt is not defined throws an error.

Comment: You're right, it seems that was deprecated, I'll update my answer

Comment: All I know is Session-id is not available for external java-script files where as the MVC view opened in browser will have the Session-id. And I know is in post type call the session-id is compulsory will be transferred to server and get type call doesn't need a session-id. So how come server will give access to post type request that doesn't have session id?. Share your opinion

Comment: I'm not an expert in the under-the-hood workings, but I believe that the action doesn't check for a session-id, it simply looks for a POST request to respond to.  Using the AntiForgeryToken gives it something unique that isn't known by an outside application/site that it can check against.

Comment: Thanks I will raise an other question to get the details.

Answer (score 1):

Follow These solution project into your code.
Third solution is final solution which can work as you need.

(1) Use @Html.AntiForgeryToken into your page
(2) Try to use Rourte method to call action
       [Route("{action=index}")] //default action 
(3) Finally You can use Encryption technique for making url

Answer (score 0):

Adding the [HttpPost] action verb simply means only posts can hit that action (as you see in your code).

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to bind an action to a specific button, your controller is basically REST.

The button is executing JavaScript (the Ajax call) from a client browser to hit the action (regardless of what button and where it is located or a hacker running JavaScript directly in the browser, the controller interprets both requests the same and cannot differentiate). Your best bet is to add some security with authentication so only certain users can hit that action.